# how did git handle one of several patches?

Tags: linux, git, patch

Let's say we have 5 patches for a file, and 4 of the patches changed the file content and add new lines. But we can still apply a single patch 5 to the git tree. Why? Since I thought the line numbers has changed, and so the line contents didn't match any more. How does git determine which line I made a change? Through the three line context of the change? I don't think it is plausible.

BTW, how to generate a number zero patch like [PATCH 0/5]? It seems format patch can only generate from 0001.

Comment: Why do you find it un-plausible?  See also the `patch` command.

Comment: @VonC Because what if there are several occurrence of a context, or the previous patch created a context, then the outcome of barely applying patch 5 would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Through the three line context of the change?

This is how [`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) describes it:

> Ensure at least `<n>` lines of surrounding context match before and after each change.
>   When fewer lines of surrounding context exist they all must match.

So yes, even if the line *numbers* changed, the context is still key in determining if a patch should apply or not.

---

Regarding the numbering aspect, I didn't test, but see if the `--start-number` option of [`git format-patch` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch.html) can help:

```
--start-number <n>
```

> Start numbering the patches at `<n>` instead of 1.

Comment: Seems all the problems was explained very well in man patch. Thank @torek for answering too.

Comment: Just still don't get how to generate the [PATCH 0/n]... Anyone knows that?

Comment: @dspjm I have edited my answer to suggest an option to try (regarding patch numbering).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it is not the way it works, we use an option called cover* to do it. start-number has to be no less than 1.